# How To Make Multiple Labels Appear In JQuery Range Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to make a slider say two separate things. I want the input above the slider to say the dollar amount (between 20 and 45) with twenty steps of $1.25 -- but i want the actual handle to say only single integer answers like 1..2..3..4..all the way to 20, so the first position would read (1) in the handle and ($20) above it and the second step of the slider would read (2) in the slider circle and ($21.25) above it.

Below is my code so far:

```
$(function() {

    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 20,
        max: 45,
        step: (1.25),
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $("span[class*=" + id + "]").text(ui.value);
            $("input[class*=" + id + "]").val(ui.value);
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
        }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ).toFixed( 2 ));    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for... Check the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rx4cm4q7/4/

```
$(function () {

    $("#slider").slider({

        value: 0,
        min: 20,
        max: 45,
        step: (1.25),

        slide: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(ui);
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var x = (ui.value - 20)/1.25;
            console.log(x);
            $("#amount").html("$" + ui.value);
            $("#step").html("<B>" +x+"</b>");
        }
    });

});
```